# inventoryData returns undefined because $http.get is asynchronous, how do I refactor code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making the following http get call to acquire an html page source code and then parse through it.

For some reason, it keeps returning undefined.

How can I fix it?

> **Update:** It seems that `$http.get()` is asynchronous, so how would I go about returning a value from it?

```
function checkInventory() {
  var newReqObj = DataService.getFormData();
  var store = newReqObj.store;
  var code = newReqObj.code;
  var size = newReqObj.size;

  if(store === 'nike') {
        var inventoryData = checkNike(store, code, size);
        $log.debug(inventoryData);
        return inventoryData;
    }
}

function checkNike(store, code, size) {
    var inventoryData = {
        'qtyAvailable': 0,
        'maxOrder': 0,
        'size': 0,
        'name': '',
        'price': '',
        'url': '',
        'code': code
    };

    var url = 'http://www.nike.co.uk/search?q=' + code;
    checkNikeUrl(url, size, inventoryData);
}

function checkNikeUrl(url, size, inventoryData) {
    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var html = response.data;

        inventoryData.qtyAvailable = utility.getProductQty(html, size);
        inventoryData.maxOrder = utility.getProductMaxOrder(html, size);
        inventoryData.size = size;
        inventoryData.name = utility.getProductName(html);
        inventoryData.price = utility.getProductPrice(html);
        inventoryData.url = url;

        return inventoryData;
    })
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) Basically, `$http.get()` is asynchronous; you can't just return a value from it.

Comment: How can the code be refactored so that it returns a value. I am running a process that needs all the data to be returned after the submit button is pressed.

Comment: Read the answers on duplicate question...

Comment: I see  you are using `then`.  If you are using promises,  you  can return the Promise and control the flow using promises

Comment: @hlfrmn it means I have to refactor my code to use `$q.defer()` right? But I am not sure how to do this...

Comment: @methuselah more like `function checkNikeUrl(){return $http.get(function(){return x;})}` And the usage is `checkNikeUrl().then();` I suggest you read the linked answer. It describes the solution nicely.

Comment: @methuselah Hi can you please post the full code? With the calling function from where checkInventory() is getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add 2 returns in yout code.

First:

```
 $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
```

should be

```
return $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
```

And second

```
  checkNikeUrl(url, size, inventoryData);
```

should be

```
return checkNikeUrl(url, size, inventoryData);
```

EDIT

and i think that

```
var inventoryData = checkNike(store, code, size);
```

should be just

```
return checkNike(store, code, size);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the code as follows:

```
function checkInventory() {
   var newReqObj = DataService.getFormData();
   var store = newReqObj.store;
   var code = newReqObj.code;
   var size = newReqObj.size;

     if(store === 'nike') {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        checkNike(store, code, size).then(function(response){
            var inventoryData = response;
        $log.debug(inventoryData);

        deferred.resolve(inventoryData);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
    }
}

function checkNike(store, code, size) {
  var inventoryData = {
    'qtyAvailable': 0,
    'maxOrder': 0,
    'size': 0,
    'name': '',
    'price': '',
    'url': '',
    'code': code
  };

  var url = 'http://www.nike.co.uk/search?q=' + code;
  return checkNikeUrl(url, size, inventoryData);
}

function checkNikeUrl(url, size, inventoryData) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get(url).then(function(response) {
        var html = response.data;

        inventoryData.qtyAvailable = utility.getProductQty(html, size);
        inventoryData.maxOrder = utility.getProductMaxOrder(html, size);
        inventoryData.size = size;
        inventoryData.name = utility.getProductName(html);
        inventoryData.price = utility.getProductPrice(html);
        inventoryData.url = url;

        deferred.resolve(inventoryData);
    })

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

You can use this and the whichever method calls the checkInventory() method, they can catch the promise and process the inventory value returned.